# Setterm white on raspbian not really "white"

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm using the following commands in a bash script, which is looping videos with omxplayer
on a rasperry pi:

```
setterm -cursor off -background white -foreground white
setterm -term linux -clear
```

The following video file has a white background.

But the above setterm command is producing more a "grey" than white background, while
the colours in the videos are perfectly displayed. The raspi is connected via HDMI to
a standard PC display. So the loop gaps are visible due to the colour change form grey to white.

Is there any tweak I can get a "bright white" background in the terminal?

Comment: This is independent of the shell. The terminal provides a palette of individual colors, but the actual visible color associated with each entry is entirely up to the terminal emulator. That is, the shell can say "use color 3", but it is the terminal emulator that shows color 3 as, say, green. `setterm -background white` actually just selects the color slot that is traditionally, but by no means required to be, set to white.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this hint. But I have no gui running .. so where can I define what is "white" meant to be. Or can I use any RGB style colour, lets say #ffffff or an ANSI colour scheme?

Comment: I'd also love to know. Experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but I hit a similar problem and came across this.

The underlying cause is that the terminal uses more intense colors to emulate bold text, as console fonts don't support that. Those intense colors are not available as background colors.
See [this table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) for the complete mapping.

However, you can redefine the color mapping on thy fly using escape sequences:

```
echo -en "\e]P7ffffff"
              ||
              |+--- RGB color
              +---- ANSI color code (0..F), 7 is the one used for regular white
```

When resetting the terminal, the colors are reset to defaults.
Modifying these defaults is yet another, really persistent option you have -- change the colorscheme via the kernel parameters `vt.default_{red,grn,blu}`:

```
vt.default_red=0x00,0xaa,0x00,0xaa,0x00,0xaa,0x00,0xaa,0x55,0xff,0x55,0xff,0x55,0xff,0x55,0xff
vt.default_grn=0x00,0x00,0xaa,0x55,0x00,0x00,0xaa,0xaa,0x55,0x55,0xff,0xff,0x55,0x55,0xff,0xff
vt.default_blu=0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0x55,0x55,0x55,0x55,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff
               |    |    |    |
               |    |    |    +- ...
               |    |    +------ RGB color for ANSI color code 2
               |    +----------- RGB color for ANSI color code 1
               +---------------- RGB color for ANSI color code 0
```

See [this thread on the ArchLinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1312413#p1312413) for more information.

(Regarding the original question: This might still mess up your video colors, as a color that could before used for gray is now white)